# Video Source and Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got the following problem. I need to save a link to a FB video added by user in order to play it in the future. When I use Graph API's method 'me/videos/uploaded' it returns an URL as source parameter. I can use it to see the video but only for some period of time (one day perhaps). Is there any way to automatically determine a link to a video that works permanently?

Here is an example of source of a video:

`"embed_html": "<object width="320" height="240" ><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/1365218093993" /><embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/1365218093993" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="320" height="240"></embed></object>",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/DggDhA4z4tO.gif",
         "source": "http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/cfs-ak-snc6/81281/459/1365218093993_56875.mp4?oh=d6b577b50bbbce2424dda238ac4e8043&oe=4E540600&__gda__=1314129408_fbaa130dd98e78430748ee9c4c974fc2"`

Any help will be much appreciated,
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the URL the comes in the `embed_html` parameter as part of the `<embed>` tag? In your case:

```
http://www.facebook.com/v/1365218093993
```

This should permanently redirect to the video. At least it works today, two weeks after you asked the question.

Comment: This redirects to a swf compiled version, not the source video. Any luck on this?

Comment: @JasonSmith have you found a solution to this problem?